# Nested commands with parametrized names

Tags: macros

Inside a command I would like to define multiple new commands. Their names are parametrized by arguments, but they should also be able to call each other during definition. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}  

\newcommand{\defFooAndBar}[2]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname foo#1\endcsname{#2}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname bar#1\endcsname{let us expand \foo#1 and show #2.}
}

\defFooAndBar{One}{the second argument}
\defFooAndBar{Two}{the second argument}

\begin{document}  

\fooOne
\barOne
\fooTwo
\barTwo

\end{document}
```

However, there is an error generated:

> ! Undefined control sequence. \barOne ->let us expand \foo 
>                                One and show the argument.

Apparently, Latex puts a blank space after \foo and therefore \foo#1 is not treated as a single entity. Is it possible to indicate the parser that they belong together?

Comment: It should be `\csname foo#1\endcsname` in the second line of the definition.

Comment: Related question: [macros - calling a command using an input variable - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291169/macros-calling-a-command-using-an-input-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX works strictly with *tokens*. In your code

```
let us expand \foo#1 and show #2.
```

`\foo` makes a single token and `#1` is a parameter token that will be replaced by the actual argument at macro call. So when you do

```
\defFooAndBar{One}{the second argument}
```

the second command is defined as

```
let us expand \foo One and show the second argument
```

(the space is just to show where one token ends).

Solution: form the token with `\csname...\endcsname` just as you do for building the tokens to be defined:

```
\newcommand{\defFooAndBar}[2]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname foo#1\endcsname{#2}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname bar#1\endcsname{let us expand \csname foo#1\endcsname and show #2.}%
}
```

No `\expandafter` is needed here; it is necessary instead for forming the token `\fooOne` (or similar) *before* `\newcommand` enters into action.