# macros - calling a command using an input variable

Tags: macros

In the process of a project, I realized it would be helpful if I could do as follows. Say I have a list of different commands (simplified):

```
\newcommand{\AA}{...}
\newcommand{\AB}{...}
\newcommand{\AC}{...}
...
\newcommand{\AZ}{...}
```

Now I want a command that can call one of these commands (based on input):

```
\newcommand{\caller}[1]{\A#1}
```

The example above won't work, but how would I go accomplishing something that has such a functionality?

Comment: See also: [macros - Using command parameters to use another command - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255741/using-command-parameters-to-use-another-command)

Answer (score 6):

You have to construct the macro name with `\csname A#1\endcsname`.

In fact, a lot of package or class code makes use of this `\csname ...\endcsname` construction and it's not restricted to `LaTeX`, since both macros are `TeX` primitives actually.

Please note: `\AA` is already defined, providing a Scandinavian character, i.e.s something like Å (But since the command names seemed to be simplified, this won't be an issue, I think)

If `\A#1` is not defined `\csname A#1\endcsname` expands to `\relax`, i.e. it does nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}



\newcommand{\AB}{bar}
\newcommand{\AC}{foobar}

\newcommand{\caller}[1]{%
  \csname A#1\endcsname%
}


\begin{document}
\caller{A}

\caller{B}

\caller{C}

\caller{Z}
\end{document}
```

As you can see `\caller{A}` works (since `\AA` is defined) and `\caller{Z}` does nothing (since `\AZ` isn't defined)

[image]

Comment: You beat me to the answer by a few seconds. :-)

Comment: @Mico: I am becoming an answering machine ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ... please leave a message at the tone? :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: lol, sure