# Call a command where part of the command name is given as input?

Tags: macros, packages

This seems obvious but I can't seem to find what I need via a search (I can't figure out a good search term I guess).

So what I'm looking for is to have a command that takes in a string, and then calls a command whose name contains that string. For reference the command will be in a sty file.

MWE:

Sty file:

```
\newcommand{\foo@tempinput}
    {This works I hope!}
\newcommand{\DesiredMacro}[1]
    {\csname \foo@#1\endcsname}
```

Actual Document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Customstyfile}
\begin{document}
\DesiredMacro{tempinput}
\end{document}
```

And ideally that would output "This works I hope!"

I know the above doesn't work because the \csname isn't expanding the #1, but I'm unsure as to if \csname can be used as a way of executing a command, or if it's only used to define a command?

I want to do this so that I can have a host of commands, and the user can execute the one they need by typing in a name, which protecting the command itself from the user (and avoiding having the user need to know the more complicated command names. I want to be able to have the user input only be a part of the command name).

Thanks!

Comment: See also [macros - calling a command using an input variable - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291169/macros-calling-a-command-using-an-input-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using, as the OP did, `\csname \foo@#1\endcsname`, a macro is invoked with the name formed by substituting the definition of `\foo` followed by argument 1, `#1`.  But what the OP's main code suggests isn't that the value of `\foo` is desired, but rather the letters "foo" themselves, so that the macro being invoked has the "name" of "foo#1", where `#1`'s value is substituted.

Thus, eliminating the backslash prior to `foo` in the definition of `\DesiredMacro` takes care of the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{Customstyfile}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo@tempinput}
    {This works I hope!}
\newcommand{\DesiredMacro}[1]
    {\csname foo@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\DesiredMacro{tempinput}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, I'm a moron, that slash was the problem. Figures... bang my head against a wall for an hour over a backslash. Story of my life heh, thanks Steven!

Comment: @Jason Glad to help.  Yes, I do think the term "backslash" is aptly named, for all the injury it causes.